# Are there any natural preservatives that can be used in Soups or Stews?

Tags: additives

I make a lot soups and various stews and they don't seem to last more than a few days - are there any natural preservatives that can be added to them that will increase their refrigerator life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If cooled and stored properly (minimize air space in the container), most soups will should last in the refrigerator up to 5 days.  Do you really want to be eating the same soup that long?  I would suggest dividing your soups into smaller sized containers and freezing it so you have a wide selection available at any given time.

Depending on the ingredients most soups can be succesfully frozen for long term storage.

Dairy based items are more likely to curdle/separate after thawing so you'd be better to add the cream/milk when you're reheating it.

Chunks of potato or pasta are likely to break up a bit and have a more mealy consistency so it would also be better to leave the potato out and add to it and cook when reheating.