# Lemon juice as a natural preservative for soups

Tags: soup

Can lemon juice be used as a natural preservative for soups?

Additionally, Russian soup Borsch has a lot  of cabbage in it, as far as I know that makes it last longer. Do you think cabbage can help a soup to be preserved longer?

What are other natural preservatives that can be used for soups?

There is this question [Are there any natural preservatives that can be used in Soups or Stews?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3900/are-there-any-natural-preservatives-that-can-be-used-in-soups-or-stews) but the answer doesn't address lemon juice or cabbage or any other natural preservatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that will keep bacteria and other spoilage microorganisms from growing will extend shelf life.  Acidity and salt are the most common historical preservatives, since they create inhospitable environments for many microorganisms (or only allow the growth of ones that are less harmful).  In high concentrations, sugar can also function in this way, as in jams or jellies (though this is probably not applicable to soups).  Unfortunately, any soup with enough salt and/or acidity to stop bacterial growth entirely will probably be unpalatable.

That said, lemon juice is highly acidic, so it's likely that it could prevent spoilage a *little* longer than in soups without it.  However, unless you're adding a *lot* of lemon juice, chances are this effect will not be long enough to call it a "preservative" -- but it *might* make your soup last a day or two longer in the fridge.  A fairly acidic soup using things like tomatoes, lemon juice, vinegar, etc. will generally last a little longer than a similar one without those ingredients.

Nevertheless, the normal storage recommendations for soup should still be observed.  Soup in general is very perishable.  Stocks and broths are a near ideal growth medium for any bacteria that might contaminate them, and various ingredients in soups could contain spore-forming microorganisms that are not completely killed during cooking.  More importantly, not all spoilage -- even that from dangerous bacterias -- produces odors or molds that could be easily spotted.  Thus, while adding more acid to soup probably makes it safer a little longer, I still wouldn't depend on it to last more than a few days even using proper cooling procedures and stored under proper refrigeration.

As for cabbage, I'm not aware of any significant anti-microbial properties.  It's possible that soups which contain more vegetable matter (like cabbage) will also contain less meat and other ingredients prone to fast spoilage, but the cabbage by itself isn't likely to have a significant effect.

Comment: To put it another way, the normal way of *really* preserving things with acid is pickling them. The amount of lemon juice you'll actually want to add to a soup or stew is not going to be anywhere near that kind of acidity.

Comment: @Jefromi - yes, though I think "really preserving" depends on context. I rather doubt the question here was asking whether a little lemon juice would cause soup to be shelf-stable for months or years, as pickling would do. For bread, for example, a "preservative" impedes molding and staling for a few extra days; I assume in the context of soup that it would mean a similar timescale. And acid or salt will often retard microbe growth, even in smaller quantities, compared to without them.